# How can I stop SQL from validating an OPENROWSET query when its not going to be executed?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a problem where a stored procedure is throwing an error because it's trying to run/validate an `OPENROWSET` query inside it that it doesn't actually have to execute.

The stored procedure that looks something like this:

```
IF (@flagA = 1)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #tmpData(Column1, Column2, Column3)
    SELECT A, B, C
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM OPENROWSET(
            'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
            'Text; HDR=Yes; Database=\\server\tmpFiles', 
            'SELECT * FROM FileA.txt')
    ) as T
END

IF (@flagB = 1)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #tmpData(Column1, Column2, Column3)
    SELECT D, E, F
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0', 
        'Excel 8.0;Database=\\server\tmpFiles\FileB.xls', 
        'SELECT * FROM [Sheet$]')
    ) as T
END

IF (@flagC = 1)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #tmpData(Column1, Column2, Column3)
    SELECT G, H, I
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0', 
        'Excel 8.0;Database=\\server\tmpFiles\FileC.xls', 
        'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
    ) as T
END
```

Note that each `OPENROWSET` references a different file, in a different format, with different column names.

My problem is that if one of the files doesn't exist, or exists in the wrong format (such as someone uploading a FileB as FileC by mistake), I get an error when the procedure tries to run, even though that `OPENROWSET` query is never meant to get executed.

For example, if FileB doesn't exist and you try to run the procedure with `@flagB = 0`, it will throw an error saying it can't find the linked server for `FileB`

Or if a user uploads a `FileB` as a `FileC` by mistake, then corrects themselves by removing `FileC` from the form, it will throw an error saying `Cannot process the object "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"` next time the procedure runs because FileC won't have a sheet named `Sheet1`, even though `@flagC = 0`

How can I prevent SQL from validating the `OPENROWSET` queries if they're not the ones getting executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of options available.  One of them is to use dynamic SQL for your insert calls.  That way, validation doesn't actually occur until the execution occurs.  For your example, it could look like:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

IF (@flagA = 1)
BEGIN
set @sql = N'
    INSERT INTO #tmpData(Column1, Column2, Column3)
    SELECT A, B, C
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM OPENROWSET(
            ''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'', 
            ''Text; HDR=Yes; Database=\\server\tmpFiles'', 
            ''SELECT * FROM FileA.txt'')
    ) as T
';
END

IF (@flagB = 1)
BEGIN
set @sql = N'
    INSERT INTO #tmpData(Column1, Column2, Column3)
    SELECT D, E, F
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0'', 
        ''Excel 8.0;Database=\\server\tmpFiles\FileB.xls'', 
        ''SELECT * FROM [Sheet$]'')
    ) as T
';
END

IF (@flagC = 1)
BEGIN
set @sql = N'
    INSERT INTO #tmpData(Column1, Column2, Column3)
    SELECT G, H, I
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0'', 
        ''Excel 8.0;Database=\\server\tmpFiles\FileC.xls'', 
        ''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'')
    ) as T
';
END

execute sp_executesql @sql;
```

In this case, validation wouldn't occur until runtime.  The downside is that troubleshooting gets harder because you're now trying to debug dynamic SQL.

You might also be able to merge the several separate statements into one.

A second alternative is to split the call out into separate procedures.  I would put this at a distant second-place, mostly because it's easy to abuse this and start pretending that T-SQL stored procedures are equivalent to C-style methods, forgetting that there can be significant performance differences.  Anyhow, move the INSERT statements into three separate procedures and pass in any necessary parameters, like so:

```
IF (@flagA = 1)
BEGIN
    exec InsertFlagA @parms1;
END

IF (@flagB = 1)
BEGIN
    exec InsertFlagB @parms2;
END

IF (@flagC = 1)
BEGIN
    exec InsertFlagB @parms3;
END
```

You couldn't do this with a temp table, so that might throw this option out unless you had a permanent "temporary" table available (or used a global temp table).

If you did want to use a temp table, you could change the exec statement to `insert into #tmpData exec InsertFlagA @parms1`.

Comment: Ugh I was hoping SQL provided a way to disable this validation so I didn't have to use dynamic SQL or multiple procedures + global tables. Thank you though, I'll accept your answer if nobody can provide a better one :) I suppose as a 3rd option I could also have my application copy a template version of each file when the file isn't specified to ensure it exists and is in the correct format...